# RequiredFieldValidator Control displays the Error Text on Page_Load

Tags: asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I am having trouble with the `<asp:RequiredFieldValidator>` in this code.

```
<asp:Label ID="email_Label" runat="server" Text="Email"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="email_Text" runat="server" MaxLength="40" Width="250"></asp:TextBox> *
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="email_Text" Text="Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

According to the W3schools documentation [here](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_reqfieldvalidator.asp) I have used the `<asp:RequiredFieldValidator>` correctly, however instead of displaying the label and text box the page also displays the error message. This happens on page_load so the value has not had a chance to change from the default yet. I want the error text to display after the user clicks the Save button at the bottom of the form I am building.

What is Being Displayed:

Email[*TextBox*] * Required

What Should Be displayed:

Email[*TextBox*] *

Am I missing a parent element for the validator or something. According to the example on w3schools site no parent element should be needed. In fact the way they have their example set-up is exactly what I was expecting for this.

Comment: Could you post your code-behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Validation Group` if want to display Error message on Button click. Like this.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rqtxtQName" ValidationGroup="save" ControlToValidate="txtQueueName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Some required field are missing." SetFocusOnError="True"Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

and use validation group on `Button` also.

```
  <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" ValidationGroup="save" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"/>
```

Hope it will helps.

Answer (score 3):

you should use `ErrorMessage` instead of `Text`

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="email_Text" ErrorMessage="Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to validation on save button click event then set property ValidationGroup="Group1" 
for RequiredFieldValidator  and also for save button. So it will check validation when you click save button.

And For display message you can use ErrorMessage property.

Thanks,
Hitesh

Answer (score 0):

Set the RequiredFieldValidator this way. Remove the property: 'TextRequired' & put a * inbetween the opening and closing tag.

```
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server"
 ControlToValidate="email_Text">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Also, Do not set the ErrorMessage property as this will again not fit your requirements.